# Extending the result $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{a+b} \lt a^a b^b$ to $n$ number of terms.

Tags: inequality

Prove that
$$
\left(
\frac{a+b+c\cdots k}{n}
\right) ^{a+b+c \cdots k} \lt a^a b^b c^c \cdots k^k
$$

We can prove that
$$
(1+x)^{1+x} (1-x)^{1-x} \gt 1$$ (if $x \lt 1$) and from there by assuming $x = \frac{u}{z}$ and then $u+z =a$ and $u-z =b$ we will have
$$
\left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{a+b} \lt a^a b^b$$ but how to extend this result upto $n$ number of terms?

Comment: Have you tried taking logarithms on both sides ?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, it answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find this in a book ? The author of the other questions mentions a book in the comments. I thought the formulation was a bit strange, so I edited the other question, but maybe I should have left it as it was if was copied from the book...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, it’s from Hall and Knight.

Comment: And I have used the same letters that are used in the book.